# Store user login details to DB in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I've set up authentication in Laravel 5.5 using `php artisan make:auth` etc, but now I have a problem.

I have a DB table named `user_actions` where I store what the user does in my application (such as which pages they opened, which filters they used on searches, stuff like that). I want to add logins to this table but I can't for the life of me figure out how.

The `LoginController` only contains the constructor and the `redirectTo` variable. It has `use AuthenticatesUsers` but searching the project for `AuthenticatesUsers` doesn't come up with any results except for the two mentions in the login controller file.

The `AuthServiceProvider` just has the boot method for registering policies.

In the `Register` controller there is the `create` method which creates the database entry for the user, but in `Login` I am not sure what's going on.

So where can I add in my call to store the login action to the database? Do I have to listen for an event?

Comment: So you want to track and store just login actions or all the actions they do after login?

Comment: I'm already tracking some actions users do, I just want to add logins to that list.

Comment: have you tried the auth controllers?

Comment: Then its pretty easy, you can insert a row in table where you check for user's authentication. If it goes through, save it to DB.

Comment: @madalinivascu I've been looking at the controllers for an hour and I have no idea where to actually insert my code. The logincontroller just has the contructor, surely I'm not expected to do it from there?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Where is it checked exactly? As in, which file, which method. That's my question.

Comment: Sounds like you've gone the longer route than needed.. You could've just set up a ComposerServiceProvider for all pages and then ran the log query to get the current route, username etc and store it.

Comment: @Jovan, have you figured this out yet? I have just coded something up that does pretty much everything you have mentioned.

Comment: @Option The first answer here solves the issue for authenticated users but I would love to see your solution too if not too much trouble.

Comment: My methods slightly differs as it'll log every click a user actions on each page. It'll state whether its a POST / GET. What user performed said action and what page it was actioned on along with dates. Perhaps a little too far fetched for what you was initially looking for. If the answer has been given and has worked for you, please ensure to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Yes, I think that's a bit of an overkill for me. I only need to log about 5 or 6 actions, and with the login now solved, that concludes my list. Thanks!

Comment: @user2486 Because I had a controller mistake entirely unrelated to the question, fixed that and the question became meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add an authenticated method to your login controller, this method gets called right after the authentication process

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;


class LoginController extends Controller  
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
      * @param Request $request
      * @param Authenticatable $user
      * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
    */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, Authenticatable $user)
    {
        /* Your db inserts */
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo);
    }
}
```

if you also want to catch login attempts and / or failed logins, you can override the login function, because authenticated only gets called after a successful login

Comment: This causes an error: `Type error: Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\User given, called in /path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php on line 104`

Comment: I updated my answer @jovan , seems like u did not have `use AuthenticatesUsers;` in your login class

Comment: I did, but I didn't have `use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default login function

```
 use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers {
        login as protected userLogin;
    }
    public function login(Request $request) {
    //you db logic
    return $this->userLogin();
    }
```

all the login logic you can find it in `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth`

or as you sad use a [event listener](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#events)

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

class UserEventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * Handle user login events.
     */
    public function onUserLogin($event) {
        //log data in db
     }

    /**
     * Handle user logout events.
     */
    public function onUserLogout($event) {
      //log data in db
     }

    /**
     * Register the listeners for the subscriber.
     *
     * @param  Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     */
    public function subscribe($events)
    {
        $events->listen(
            'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login',
            'App\Listeners\UserEventSubscriber@onUserLogin'
        );

        $events->listen(
            'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout',
            'App\Listeners\UserEventSubscriber@onUserLogout'
        );
    }

}
```